# Forget about the $\cos,\sin$ function, show that $\left|1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!-x^6/6!+...\right|\leq1$

Tags: calculus

> Forget about the $\cos,\sin$ function, show that $\left|1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!-x^6/6!+...\right|\leq1$

I tried to use differentiation, but it doesn't seems helpful. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't differentiation help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define $$f(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

One can readily see this converges for any $x$. Note that $$f''+f=0$$ whence $$f'f''+ff'=0$$ which means $$f'^2+f^2=K$$

By plugging in values we see $K=1$; thus $$f'^2+f^2=1$$ whence we must have $|f'|,|f|\leq 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Readily because it's alternating and eventually strictly decreasing in absolute value?

Comment: @dfeuer It is absolutely convergent.

Comment: You could use the ratio test to prove absolute convergence or just quickly use the AST for conditional convergence.

Comment: I just realized the ratio test does it.

Comment: The weird thing, to me, is that the first several terms can actually get large for $|x|\gg1$, but then things have to cancel out somehow.

Comment: @dfeuer The point is that for any $x$ we can use up enough terms to get the value inside $[-1,1]$-

Comment: Yes, you've proven that, and I know it works; it's just "feels" weird.

Comment: A small remark. From the first equation in Peter's solution, $|f''| \leq 1$ for all $x$ also. By putting $y(x)=f'(x)$ and following the same steps leads to $|f^{(k)}| \leq 1$ for all $x$.